# My email has been hacked, now what?

Tags: email

I was asked this today by a friend, and not being an expert in this field all I could say was,

- Reset/change passwords
- Run antivirus

Is there a good quicklist of todo's to ensure that things go "back to normal"?

Comment: What Mail-System is that? Web, imap or pop3? On what system?

Comment: How do you know that you mail acc was hacked?

Comment: If you're really sure it was hacked, don't forget to report it to the police.

Comment: Let people know you were hacked, naturally - maybe through social networking or something.

Answer (score 1):

Check all settings.  You know... make sure the backup email address in the settings (the one that a password would get emailed to) hasn't been changed.  Things like that.

Institute a better/stronger password policy.

Add anti-malware/anti-spyware to the anti-virus list.

But honestly, if the computer itself was compromised, which would require you to have to scan the system for a virus or infection of some sort... according to Jesper Johansson, Security Program Manager at Microsoft...

> The only way to clean a compromised system is to flatten and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change/reset password.... stronger password and something completely different from your normal set of passwords and do it from a different computer just in case your main computer is compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your password is strong with upper and lower case with special characters and numbers, I assume this was a hotmail/gmail type account. once you changed it. Run some spyware like spybot and some AV, but there is not much more you can do (unless you rebuild). The main reason why they hack your email because your account, the password was guessed.